# Avoiding 'character argument not in range' python3 decode

Tags: python, decode

I am trying to decode the content of a `requests.get()` call to a specific url. The url which causes the problem is not always the same across multiple runs of the code, however the part of the requested content which produces the problem has a triple backslash, which gives an error when decoding using `unicode-escape`.

As a simplified version of the code running in Python 3.6.1

```
r=b'\xf0\\\xebI'
r.decode('unicode-escape').strip().replace('{','\n')
```

produces the following error:

```
OverflowError: character argument not in range(0x110000)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: decoding with 'unicode-escape' codec failed (OverflowError: character argument not in range(0x110000))
```

I would like to just skip over the part which produces the error. I am a novice python programmer so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: In this case, I would expect: 'ðëI'. Just skipping the part which induces the error is what I am after here.

Comment: Why are you decoding with unicode-escape instead of whatever encoding is specified in the response's content-type header?

Comment: Okay I was able to cook something up to decode it, check if it makes sense to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These set of steps should work in your case

```
In [1]: r=b'\xf0\\\xebI'                                                        
#Decode to utf-8 using backslashreplace
In [2]: x=r.decode('utf-8', errors='backslashreplace')                          
In [3]: x                                                                       
Out[3]: '\\xf0\\\\xebI'
#Replace the extra backslash
In [4]: y = x.replace('\\\\','\\')                                              
In [5]: y                                                                       
Out[5]: '\\xf0\\xebI'
#Encode to ascii and decode to unicode-escape
In [6]: z = y.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')                          
In [7]: z                                                                       
Out[7]: 'ðëI'
```

Note that this also works in case of double slash, your normal scenario

```
r=b'\xf0\\xebI'
x=r.decode('utf-8', errors='backslashreplace')
y = x.replace('\\\\','\\')
z = y.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
print(z)
#ðëI
```

Answer (score 1):

The data appears to be encoded as latin-1<sup>*</sup>, so the simplest solution would be to decode and then remove the backslashes.

```
>>> r=b'\xf0\\\xebI'
>>> r.decode('latin-1').replace('\\', '')
'ðëI'
```

<sup>*</sup> I'm guessing latin-1 (also known as ISO-8859-1) - the response's content-type header should specify the encoding used, which could possibly be one of the other ISO-8859-* encodings.

Comment: Thank your for the response - this worked for me. Upon further inspection, I find the encoding to be utf-8, however using this strategy with this encoding type specified does not work. I'll have to dig into this deeper, but for now this solution is working for me. Thank you again.

Comment: This might not work if you have the normal double slash

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I was just about to comment that, as the OP has confirmed the encoding is utf-8, your answer is more correct :)

Comment: Haha, guess the OP should accept my answer then lol! I updated my answer for the normal case @melo_gonzo with double backslash too :)

Comment: Thank you both - I appreciate all the help as I am just a beginner!